# How to plug a custom scope in the dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, scopes

I have followed the tutorial for creating a scope found here

http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorials/unity-8-scope-example-openclipart/

I managed to modify the code and have the scope retrieve artist metadata from
the Spotify web API. I can load the scope and I get the window with the scope and
a few controls. Now I was wondering if it's possible to use the scope I have created to
show results in the desktop dash? Is this possible at all? Or the scope is supposed to work only
with Unity 8 and so I can't use it on a trusty desktop install?

Answer (score 0):

Unity 7 and Unity 8 are using different APIs for scopes. Scopes written against the new API for Unity 8 will not work under Unity 7. However, they should work just fine under the Unity 8 preview session.

Comment: Do you know how the scope should be installed in order to be used in the Unity 8 preview?